# Multiple Rows to One row. Getting all days instead of those that match course. Below are results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select distinct
       dbo.Courses.DisplayName AS CourseInternalName,
       dbo.courses.CourseID, 
       stuff((select distinct ','+ (case when CourseSchedules.dayid = 1 then 'Mon'
                                         when CourseSchedules.dayid = 2 then 'Tue'
                                         when CourseSchedules.dayid = 3 then 'Wed' 
                                         when CourseSchedules.dayid = 4 then 'Thur'
                                         when CourseSchedules.dayid = 5 then 'Fri'
                                         when CourseSchedules.dayid = 6 then 'Sat'
                                         when CourseSchedules.dayid = 7 then 'Sun'
                                     end) 
               FROM  dbo.Courses 
               left outer join dbo.CourseSchedules 
                    on dbo.Courses.CourseGUID = dbo.CourseSchedules.CourseGUID
               for xml path('')),1,1,'') AS Days

from  dbo.Courses 
left outer join dbo.CourseSchedules 
     on dbo.Courses.CourseGUID = dbo.CourseSchedules.CourseGUID
Where courses.CourseID = 5815
```

Result is:

```
CourseInternalName  CourseID    Days
Red Cross Sunfish - CC  5815    Mon,Fri,Wed,Tue,Thur,Sat
```

this is all the days of week and not just the ones the course runs on.

Also need to order days.

If I remove the from clause in the Stuff statement I get the right days but in multiple rows.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your left joins are redundant, causing your query to return unexpected results.

Try this instead:

First, create and populate sample tables (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
CREATE TABLE Courses
(
    CourseID int,
    DisplayName varchar(10),
    CourseGUID uniqueidentifier DEFAULT(NEWID())
)

CREATE TABLE CourseSchedules
(
    dayid int,
    CourseGUID uniqueidentifier
)

INSERT INTO Courses(CourseID, DisplayName)
VALUES (5815, 'Test')

INSERT INTO CourseSchedules
SELECT 1, CourseGUID FROM Courses UNION
SELECT 3, CourseGUID FROM Courses UNION
SELECT 5, CourseGUID FROM Courses
```

The query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       dbo.Courses.DisplayName AS CourseInternalName,
       dbo.courses.CourseID, 
       STUFF((SELECT ','+ CASE WHEN dayid = 1 THEN 'Mon'
                               WHEN dayid = 2 THEN 'Tue'
                               WHEN dayid = 3 THEN 'Wed' 
                               WHEN dayid = 4 THEN 'Thur'
                               WHEN dayid = 5 THEN 'Fri'
                               WHEN dayid = 6 THEN 'Sat'
                               WHEN dayid = 7 THEN 'Sun'
                          END
               FROM  dbo.CourseSchedules 
               WHERE dbo.CourseSchedules.CourseGUID = dbo.Courses.CourseGUID
               ORDER BY dayid
               FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS Days
FROM  dbo.Courses 
WHERE courses.CourseID = 5815
```

Results:

```
CourseInternalName  CourseID    Days
Test                5815        Mon,Wed,Fri
```

Comment: Zohar Peled, this worked thank you.  I still have the problem of the day order.  This is part of a much larger query and I have been unable to get the numbers or days in order on the row.

Comment: Add an `Order by dayid` in the subquery. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Zhohar, that worked, I did try that, but was obviously putting the orderby in the wrong place.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from your subquery your not telling it to select only one course you are telling it to select any course that matches a course in Courses. The correction is below.  And actually as you subquery is completely separate there is no need for the first join

```
select distinct
       dbo.Courses.DisplayName AS CourseInternalName,
       dbo.courses.CourseID, 
       stuff((select distinct ','+ (case when CourseSchedules.dayid = 1 then 'Mon'
                                         when CourseSchedules.dayid = 2 then 'Tue'
                                         when CourseSchedules.dayid = 3 then 'Wed' 
                                         when CourseSchedules.dayid = 4 then 'Thur'
                                         when CourseSchedules.dayid = 5 then 'Fri'
                                         when CourseSchedules.dayid = 6 then 'Sat'
                                         when CourseSchedules.dayid = 7 then 'Sun'
                                     end) 
               FROM  dbo.CourseSchedules
               Where CourseSchedules.CourseID = 5815
               ORDER BY CourseSchedules.dayid ASC
               for xml path('')),1,1,'') AS Days

from  dbo.Courses 
Where courses.CourseID = 5815
```

Comment: Thank you Baine, but this gives me the same result.

Comment: The same result as what?  With the course id set CourseSchedules.CourseID = 5815, it should not give you any other course days

Comment: Hi Baine, My question was probably not clear.  the course ID was just an example.  the problem is now solved. thanks for you help